# generate java snippets from multiple feature files

Tags: intellij-idea, cucumber

How do I generate java snippets in IntelliJ from multiple feature files in the same cucumber project? When I run any features after the first I get a 'java reached end of file while parsing' error message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Start with fixing the parsing error. The rest will take care of itself. That is, snippets you can use will be generated.